# Changing default signature in Outlook, Windows 10

Tags: outlook, linked-accounts

I don't want to see "Sent from Windows Mobile 10" added to my messages -- I do want to see my own signature instead.

There is an answer to a similar question at [How to disable default email signature in Windows 10 (Lumia 950)?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/11992/how-to-disable-default-email-signature-in-windows-10-lumia-950), but it is no longer applicable; the UI is different, and trying to do something similar with today's version of the OS does not work for me. In settings I get to "signature" and try to select an account, but the list comes up empty.

I do have two email accounts; they are linked, maybe this is the problem, but no clue how to proceed. Any help (relevant to today's version of Windows Mobile 10 on a Lumia 950) would be most welcome.

Comment: The UI from that answers matches what is on my Lumia 950. Are you using an insider build?

Comment: I am using the plain, standard version of the OS, updated yesterday (version 1511, OS build 10.0 .10586.545).

Outlook --> Settings --> Signature leads to a a page with a drop-down menu that is empty.


I have two email accounts, linked. But none of them appears. So I get stuck, no way to edit the signature.


This problem makes it essentially impossible for me to send email from the phone -- I cannot afford to have the default signature appended to every message, and I cannot retype my signature each time.

It very much looks like a plain bug. Anyone from Microsoft reading this?

Comment: Perhaps you could add a screenshot of what you do see at that page? As it sounds like a fault. An update has also started rolling out that will update to a later version, which *might* resolve the issue too

Comment: I was using the **same build** when I took the screenshot in your referenced post and it was taken on Aug 16, **a day before your question was asked** and it looks same till now. You might want to post a screenshot of your UI as @RowlandShaw said. However I have an assumption of your problem and posting an answer. If it's not helpful kindly let us know along with a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

- Open up the outlook app
- Settings
- Signature
- Type in what you would like

Comment: The question states that this method is not working, so perhaps you could elaborate further?

Answer (score 0):

I was using the **same build** when I took the screenshot in your referenced post and it was taken on Aug 16, **a day before your question was asked** and it looks same till now.

This problem is not due to the Linked Inbox. Even with a Linked Inbox I get the same UI.

I assume that you might have checked the *Apply to all accounts* checkbox. If this checkbox is ticked you cannot use the dropdown menu. You can turn off the signature regardless of that.

Comment: Thanks. I don't get to see an "Apply to all accounts" checkbox. Sequence of events (very simple): in Outlook I select any Inbox and then the "..." menu at the bottom right. Then I select "Settings" and from there "Signature". Then I get a page titled "Signature" where the only element below that title is "Select an account" with an blank dropdown list. Tapping that list has no effect (beyond the blank field turning grey).

Comment: Thanks. I don't get an "Apply to all accounts" checkbox. Sequence of events: in Outlook I select the "..." at the bottom right. Then "Settings" and from there "Signature". I get a page with only the title "Signature" and the text  "Select an account" with an blank dropdown list. Tapping that list has no effect.

I am at my wits' end since the phone is pretty much useless with this absurd standard signature -- I was planning to use it mostly for email .

As I wrote before I am pretty sure I hit a real bug and if someone from Microsoft could look into the matter it would be great.

Comment: @JillMcNamara So the accounts are detected in the app. Have you tried deleting and re adding accounts.